# Extension method can't be used in LINQ Expression Tree

Tags: c#, linq

I have tried to use an extension method in my LINQ query the following way (EF Code First):

```
 from user in db.Users
 join data in db.Data on user.ID equals data.User_ID
 where data.Available.ToBool()
```

The `db.Users` and `db.Data` variables are DbSet types.

Then I got the following error:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   UserData.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'Boolean ToBool(System.String)' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

The extension method is simple:

```
 public static bool ToBool(this string source)
 {
      return source=="AA";
 }
```

So I looked into expression trees and created an expression:

```
pivate readonly System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<Func<Data, bool>> Proper = d => d.Name.ToBool();
```

Now I use it like this:

```
 from user in db.Users 
 join data in db.Data.Where(Proper) on user.ID equals data.User_ID
```

I still have the same error.

What else should I use?

Comment: entity does not know how to translate your custom function to SQL query. You will need to write your own Expression, or use `where data.Available = "AA"`
[More Info](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546175.aspx)

Comment: Why won't you use this logic in `where` clause? `where data.Available == "AA"`, wouldn't this work ?

Comment: You can't expect Linq to Entities to translate your `ToBool()` method to SQL. You need to embed the criteria in the statement itself: `where data.Available == "AA"`

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, Since `db.Data` is a `DbSet<Data>` that is `IQueryable<Data>`, `Where()` would return `IQueryable<Data>`

Comment: I was under the impression that creating an expression tree handles the convert between C# and the underlying provider. Then what is the purpose of creating expression if I can use it much simpler?

Comment: @Nestor, Using an expression tree lets the provider interpret that expression in runtime, it doesn't guarantee that any expression can eventually be translated into store query.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, It will compile. `data` represents each item in `db.Data.Where(Proper)` (just like in a `foreach` statement).

Comment: @haim770 If you collect your comments into an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: if you plan to have multiple strings which will return "True", you can do  the following
`var trueStrings = new string[]{"AA", "BB"};

from user in db.Users
 join data in db.Data on user.ID equals data.User_ID
 where trueStrings.Contains(data.Available);`

Comment: @Robert It would be good, if the logic were simple, but it is more complex.

Comment: @Nestor, If you're aiming at a resuable utility function that can be used to filter collections of `Data`. You can still use your `Proper` expression with a slight change: `Expression<Func<Data, bool>> Proper = d => d.Name == "AA";`

Comment: @haim770 Yes, I figured it out. Unfortunately the whole point is about using extension methods easily in LINQ queries :)

Comment: If the logic is particularly complex then another option is to use `AsEnumerable` and do the logic in Linq to objects instead of EF.  Of course that could change the performance based on the amount of data, so it should only be used if it makes sense for your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You can use extension methods like this:

```
public static IQueryable<User> HasData(this IQueryable<User> u)
{
  return u.Datas.Any();
}
```

Used like:

```
var u=db.Users.HasData();
```

But this would return users that have any data, assuming you have a navigation property on Users to Data called `Datas` (And yes, I know the plural of Datum is Data)